# possible to have screenshot of part of a web page via command-line?

Tags: browser, web, screenshot

While I know that I can use wkhtmltoimage to have a screenshot of the whole web page (no matter how long), there doesn't seem to be a way in either wkhtmltoimage or any software that I want to have say the bottom 50% of the web-page or any arbitrary ways. Is there a way to do it via command-line or would I have to resort to use imagemagick trickery ? X is running and I don't want to use the screenshot tool. Is something from the CLI available ?

Comment: Is X running or are you trying to do this from a text only console?

Comment: X is running, maybe I should add it to the question as well.

Comment: https://github.com/marianoguerra/webshot would work, I use Shutter's "Web shot" feature. I don't think either allow you to take a picture of an arbitrary size though.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18875117/unix.stackexchange.com-questions-234816-possible-to-have-screenshot-of-part-of-a-web-page-via-command-line%3Fnoredirect%3D1-comment401504_234816_402.png From Shutter's Web shot.

Comment: that is and also can be done by wkhtmltoimage as well, no issues therein. I wanted to have one which can do arbitrary image screenshoting from the CLI. Will wait.